# How to overwrite a file after already open?

Tags: c++, file, seekg

I'm having the following problem:

my program opens a file and copy all its content to a vector. After that, i need to get back to the beginning of the file and rewrite the content in another order.

I tried using `clear` and `seekp`, but it didn't work. Can anyone help me please?

This is the code:

`first_index` is the file I'm working with:

```
first_index.clear();
first_index.seekp (0, ios_base::beg);
```

Comment: Instead of upvoting the [above comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194687/how-to-overwrite-a-file-after-already-open#comment37351957_24194687), cast the relevant *close vote* to redirect this post to the other (which already contains the answer).

Comment: Meh I'm only about 70% behind you on that, @FilipRoséen-refp but.. good enough.